# Nuxt: Axios Interceptor - Uncaught (in promise)

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I am using the follow block of code to check if a 401 (unauthorised) error is returned from the API which in this instance means the users token has expired therefore they must re-login.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    return response
}, function (error) {
    if(error.response.status === 401) {
        localStorage.clear();
        window.location = '/'
    }
    return Promise.reject(error)
})
```

This successfully redirects the user to the login page of the application though there is an error in console which doesn't appear to be breaking anything:

[image]

I'm not sure how to go about resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior of promise rejection. This error tells that promise ended  with error (rejection) and you didn't proccess (caught) it. You can add .catch() or surround it with try catch block.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch